# Camel json-validator throws Stream closed exception

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to validate a json payload against a schema and trying to use "camel-json-validator". 
Here is how I am configuring it.

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(CamelException.class, CamelExecutionException.class, Exception.class).handled(true).bean(WcaExceptionProcessor.class,
            "handleException");
    restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
            // and output using pretty print
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES");

    rest("/retrieve")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")//.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .post()
            .type(UsersRetrieveRequest.class)
            .to("direct:userRetrieve");


    from("direct:userRetrieve")
            .doTry()
                .to("json-validator:userRetrieve.json")
                .bean("wcaResource", "postUersRetrieve")

            .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
                .log("failed ******")
                .throwException(ValidationException.class, "JSon Validation exception");



}
```

When the code runs, I am expecting a validation exception if the fiield length is more than maximim allowed. However, I get exception that "java.io.IOException: Stream closed".

```
<camelContext id="template" useMDCLogging="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:contextScan/>
    <camel:template id="templatePublish" camelContextId="template"/>
</camelContext>
```

The stream caching is turned on in the camel-context xml file.
Any suggestions what I might be missing?

Comment: Try to turn on stream-caching, see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: Hi Claus. I have the streamcaching turned on in my camel conetxt in the config xml. <camelContext id="template" useMDCLogging="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true">

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I am using Camel 2.22.0

Comment: Thanks, are you able to provide a reproducer (sample project) for example as a project on githhub, or log a JIRA ticket and attach a .zip file with the sample project. We can then use that to look into the issue quicker.

Comment: I logged a JIRA ticket to not forget about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12835

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you get, so we can see from exactly where you get it